# How to run update queries saved in a permanent table?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Permanent Table Name: PermaTable1
Values:
[image]

Question is how to execute all update commands inside the table PermaTable1?

This is my query but it does not execute the update command.

DECLARE @Query1 Nvarchar(MAX)

SET @Query1= 'SELECT Query FROM dbo.PermaTable1'

EXEC(@Query1)

Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Query1 nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @Query1 += Query + N';' FROM dbo.PermaTable1;

PRINT @Query1; -- to see the first 8,192 characters

-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Query1; -- uncomment this when you trust it
```

But I have questions. Shouldn't those update queries have where clauses? Otherwise each one is going to overwrite *all* rows and basically undo all the updates that came before it. Also are these update commands really stored in the same table they affect?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the where clause. I was able to run the query now. Big help. Thanks again!